How does firing of a gun come under the law of conservation of momentum, since we are using external force?
How does firing of a gun, come under the law of conservation of momentum, since we are using external force?
Momentum of a system, is conserved in the absence of an external force. Now, if we trigger a gun, then we are applying a force on the system externally.
So, why does this example come under the momentum conservation?

you can build an electronic trigger an remove the finger force for the discussion.

For purpose of estimating a solution, you could simply disregard the force that is applied to the trigger since the impulse imparted to the gun by the discharge of the bullet will be a couple of orders of magnitude greater than the impulse imparted by the trigger finger.

When you press the trigger of a gun, it sets a hammer in motion, which strikes the base of the ammunition. This action creates an explosion that propels the bullet through the barrel. Because the initial momentum of the gun and bullet system is zero, when the bullet is fired forward, the gun experiences a recoil backward.

What about the person holding the gun. Is not the person an external force on the gun plus bullet system?

@BobD The person holding the gun is imparting the force that keeps the gun from going backwards; the gun accelerating backwards when fired causes recoil, which the person then must counteract to keep the gun from moving very far. If you had an electronically-triggered gun, then you would see it move backwards due to conservation of momentum.

You need to be careful in defining the system for which conservation of momentum is being considered. That will determine whether or not a force under consideration is external. Even if the force is external, momentum may still be conserved if the force is not relevant to the particular situation.
For example, consider only the gun and bullet as the system. Both the person holding the gun and the Earth (and its gravity) to which the person is affixed are external forces. Depending on the orientation of the gun when fired and the instant when conservation of momentum is considered, horizontal and/or vertical momentum may not be conserved.
On the other hand, if the person, gun, bullet and Earth are the system, so that we can consider the system as essentially isolated, momentum is conserved.
Hope this helps.

So if we are considering that gun is in horizontal direction while firing and gun + man + bullet is a system then momentum is conserved.

@SatwikJoshi What do you think? Are there any external horizontal forces acting on the person?

But the textbooks use only the mass of gun while conservation, it is wrong to do so or we are simply neglecting that force because it has quite low magnitude as compared to the impulsive forces acting between spring and bullet as mentioned by @Solomon slow in flag

@SatwikJoshi  I don’t know all the details given in the textbook, but I suspect it assumes the gun is unrestrained by a person so that its recoil momentum equals the bullet momentum at the instant the bullet leaves the barrel. On the other hand if the person held the gun tightly and had his/her back against a wall imbedded in the ground so that there is no recoil of the gun or person,  then momentum would not be conserved unless the momentum of the person and Earth is included.

All of this points to why, in my answer, I indicated momentum may or may not be conserved. It really depends on the details of the scenario.


What about the person holding the gun. Is not the person an external
force on the gun plus bullet system?

if you choose to treat the person firing the gun as an external system (i.e ignore the momentum of the person after the gun is fired), then momentum is not conserved. The bullet initially had zero momentum and after being fired it has nonzero momentum. If you place the person on a skateboard and treat the person (plus skateboard) as part of the system, then momentum is conserved. The skateboard is there so that we don't have to include the Earth in the system. Now after the gun is fired, the backward momentum of the person + gun + skateboard is equal in magnitude to the forward momentum of the bullet and the final total momentum is zero, which is the same as before the gun was fired. Whether or not momentum is conserved depends on how you define the boundary conditions of the system and what you consider external to the system.

Actually it isn't the external force, when you define a system including the gun and bullet.
A force can be both internal and external, it depends on your definition of the (closed) system.
So, you do apply a force to a gun, but since the system includes both you and the gun, it is a internal force, and the momentum is conserved.
In this case, the total momentum will be the gun's(+your) momentum and the momentum of the bullet.

This is for someone on a frictionless surface?

Yes, that would be more precise. If that someone is on normal surface(e.g. something like grass), so that person stays on the ground by friction, then the whole earth needs to be included as well.

Actually momentum is always conserved, we just need to include external forces factor (second terms under summation),
$$ \sum \left( p_i + \int F_idt \right) = \sum \left( p_i^{~~'} + \int F_i^{~~'}dt \right) \tag 1$$
where $~p_i, F_i$ are momentum and forces before event and $~p_i^{~~'}, F_i^{~~'}$ - momentum and forces after event.
Imagine a billiard ball is about to hit another stationary ball, but you somehow manage to push already running ball with a stick to make it run faster until it hits it's target. Hence balance equation would be :
$$ p_1 + \int F_{\text{stick}}dt = p_1~'+p_2~'$$
